# Tkinter message wrapping for text unknown reason

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: The way it should be]
[image: The way it is]

I have run into a strange behaviour of Tkinter's `Message` widget. It worked fine before, but now it is wrapping (Date and time on left image, only date on right image) when it shouldn't. I noticed time wrapped for some seconds and others not, because not all characters are the same length.

Note that the images are cropped, but the widget actually continues about 200 more pixels. I have not set `wraplength` (which weirdly enough wasn't even recognised as an option, even though it is in the docs) so that is still at its default `0` (no wrapping). I have played around a bunch but I can't figure it out.

The text is generated from a dictionary, roughly as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500+0+0')
root.configure(bg='white')

desc = tk.Message(root)
desc.configure(bg='white')
desc.pack()

description={}
description['Date'] = '11 June 2020'
description['Time'] = '21:26:26'
description['Duration'] = 0
description['Overlay'] = str(False)

descToLines = [f'{key}:\t {val}' for key, val in description.items()]
linesToString = '\n'.join(descToLines)

desc.configure(text=linesToString)
root.mainloop()
```

In fact, while verifying this minimal code, the time line `21:26:38` is now inline with `Time`, but the date still isn't. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Maybe try manually configuring the width of your widget like: `desc.configure(bg="white", width=300)` ?

Comment: The `Message` widget tries to preserve a specific aspect ratio for the text (width 50% greater than height).  If you only want it to break lines where you explicitly included a newline, you should probably be using a `Label` instead (or at least give the `Message` an explicit width, to override the aspect ratio).

Comment: Read up on [Tkinter.Message.config-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/message.htm#Tkinter.Message.config-method)[

Comment: As I stated ready, the Message is longer. It is set at 300 pixels wide, which the text doesn't even come close to. I'll try to change the aspect ratio. That seems like something that could have changed before when it broke.

Answer (score 0):

And here is how you can see what is missing: change the background color of the Message box to another color. You'll immediately see that its width is too small. Try:

```
desc.configure(bg='#FF0000')
```

And then:

```
desc.configure(bg='#00FF00', width=200)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Nope. As stated in the question, the box is actually wider than that, around 300 px. I already tried your suggestion, why else would the background be magenta.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion I set the `Message`'s width manually and it resolved the problem. What is confusing me is that I thought it would already be set using the line:
`desc.place(x=0, y=0, height=0, width=300)`, but apparently not. At least not so far as to override the `aspect` ratio.

Tl;dr: Adding `desc.configure(width=300)` at the end fixes the problem.